# Converting java calendar date to javascript date using new Date().getTimezoneOffset()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I have a calendar data that is send to the server, it contains this fields-

```
export interface CalendarDate{
    dayOfMonth: number;
    hourOfDay: number;
    minute: number;
    month: number;
    second: number;
    year: number;
}
```

I want to convert it to javascript Date with reference to the time offset calculation, I read a lot of posts in this matter, is it correct to do it like this? will it work in all cases?

```
 return new Date(modificationDate.year, modificationDate.month, modificationDate.dayOfMonth,
                modificationDate.hourOfDay, modificationDate.minute -new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), modificationDate.second);
```

Comment: What is your definition of "work"? Why not just use Date.UTC and ignore the timezone?

Comment: What do you mean? how can I use I need a date object and not a number.

Comment: I need the actual local date for display issues in UI.

Comment: What your code appears to be doing is treating UTC values as local, so you then subtract the timezone offset to get back to the correct time. If you use Date.UTC you avoid that. Provide some example input and output per [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be doing is using UTC values as local, so you then have to use the timezone offset to get back to the correct time.

No, it will not work in all cases as you are getting the timezone offset for when the function is run, not for the date you're parsing. That may differ in places where the timezone offset has changed either through government regulation or legislation, or from daylight saving. E.g. the Line Islands recently changed from -12 to +14.

So assuming the data you get is UTC, you can use Date.UTC to get the correct date and time:

```js
// data for 2018-01-01T12:00:00Z
var data = {
    dayOfMonth: 1,
    hourOfDay: 12,
    minute: 0,
    month: 0,
    second: 0,
    year: 2018
};

// Current function, uses current timezone offset regardless of date
function toDate(data) {
  return new Date(
    data.year, data.month, data.dayOfMonth, data.hourOfDay,
    data.minute - new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), data.second);
}

// Better function, pure UTC
function toDateNew(data) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(
    data.year, data.month, data.dayOfMonth, data.hourOfDay,
    data.minute, data.second));
}

console.log('Existing: ' + toDate(data).toISOString() + 
          '\nor      : ' + toDate(data).toString() + 
          '\nNew func: ' + toDateNew(data).toISOString() +
          '\nor      : ' + toDateNew(data).toString()
);
```

So now the values are parsed as UTC, setting the date's time value to the correct value. When you display the date, local values will be used that will adjust for the timezone offset for the date based on host system settings. You don't have to do anything.